# Mergesort on Vectors not sorting

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, merge, mergesort

i'm trying to do merge-sort on vectors but i don't know what my error is. I've made a desktop test and it works ok but then, when i run the code it don't know why it doesn't sort anything and fills the vector with thrash.

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;


//los vectores se pasan por referencia
void merge(vector<int>& v, int inicio, int medio, int fin){
  int primera_mitad = medio-inicio+1; //para el primer arreglo
  int segunda_mitad = fin-medio;      //para el segundo arreglo
  //copio a cada arreglo las mitades
  vector<int> n1;
  vector<int> n2;
  int i,j,k;
  for(i=0; i<primera_mitad; i++){
    n1.push_back(v[inicio+i]);
  }
  for(j = 0; j<segunda_mitad; j++){
    n2.push_back(v[medio+j+1]);
  }
  //Ahora realizo las comparaciones para volver a ingresar al vector completo los valores
  //de las mitades en orden.
  i=0;
  j=0;
  k=inicio;
  while(i<n1.size() && j<n2.size()){ //Mientras hayan elementos por pasar en ambos subarreglos(subvector)
    if(n1[i]<=n2[j]){
        v.insert(v.begin()+k, n1[i]);
        i++;
    }
    else{
      v.insert(v.begin()+k, n2[j]);
      j++;
    }
    k++;
  }
  //Puede darse el caso de que un subarreglo se vacíe mas rápido que otro, por lo que pasamos directamente
  //los demás elementos
  while(i<n1.size()){
    v.insert(v.begin()+k, n1[i]);
    i++;
    k++;
  }
  while(j<n2.size()){
    v.insert(v.begin()+k, n2[j]);
    j++;
    k++;
  }
}

void merge_sort(vector<int>& v, int inicio, int fin){
  if(inicio<fin){
    int medio = ((fin+inicio)/2);
    merge_sort(v, inicio, medio);
    merge_sort(v, medio+1, fin);
    merge(v, inicio, medio, fin);
  }
}


void print(vector<int>& v){
  cout<<endl;
  int tam = v.size();
  for(int i = 0; i<tam; i++){
    cout<<i+1<<".\t"<<v[i]<<"\n";
  }
}

int main() {
  cout<<"----------------MERGE SORT----------------\n\n";
  cout<<"\nPlease, fill the vector: \n\n";
  int a;
  bool response = true;
  vector<int> v;
  while(response){
      cout<<"\nEnter your number: ";
      cin>>a;
      v.push_back(a);
      cout<<"Another?(1/0): ";
      cin>>response;
      cout<<endl;
  }
  int tam = v.size();
  merge_sort(v, 0, tam-1);
  print(v);
  return 0;
}
```

For example, when i put this numbers as input:

```
1 4 10 5 6
```

The program gives me this output:

```
1.  1
2.  1
3.  1
4.  10
5.  10
6.  1
7.  1
8.  10
9.  1
10. 10
11. 1
12. 10
13. 1
14. 10
15. 4
16. 5
17. 6
```

Hope you help me. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Your program fails with just two numbers, let alone 5 numbers.  For example, if the input is `2 1`, you will see that the output is not `1 2`.  So you have something basically wrong, even with the smallest of input.

Comment: It looks like you are adding values to v from n1 and n2 without erasing from v first.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying from the list at the beginning, Just keep track of where you are and do a merge into a new output list. When done, REPLACE the old values with the new ones. Don't use v.insert(). v[idx] = output[idx2]

OR

You can keep your two input lists, but you still need to REPLACE the value in your list. v[idx++] = value. idx needs to start at the beginning of the first list.

In either case, you might think about using iterators instead of indexes. This way you can avoid passing the vector. You don't need random access to the structure to write a merge sort. It should work with a std::list. You can traverse the elements by using ++iter.

Comment: So, The v.insert() doesn't replace the number that is already on the position i wanna put my new number?

Comment: @CarlosAbelCórdova No, it *inserts* a new number at the location you're specifying (assuming it is within the valid iterator range of the target vector).